# opengl: Error 1 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opengl

I'm trying to run an opengl application in vs 2008 but the compiler keeps throwing me the error:

> Error 1 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Documents.obj'

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a truncation of "c:\Documents and settings" - are you referring to something in that path without using quotes?

You need to put quotes around the $(SolutionDir) because that could expand so it has spaces in it - otherwise the compiler is looking for c:\Documents.obj and "and.obj" and "Settings...\glut32.obj".

Comment: in the source code no , but in the Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies , I see : $(SolutionDir)OpenGL\Lib\glut32.lib ....etc

Comment: that would do it - you need to put quotes around the $(SolutionDir) because that could expand so it has spaces in it - otherwise the compiler is looking for c:\Documents.obj and "and.obj" and "Settings\...\glut32.obj"

Comment: yup it works....also changing the location of the project seems to work ,thanks !